# What is the cause of the recent increase in blatantly off-topic posts on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, off-topic

For the past few days, I have the feeling that there are [a lot more blatantly off-topic questions ('lost souls') on Meta Stack Exchange](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7334654#7334654). OK, that could be just a feeling, so I've created a [short script](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/b2c69bc646f6174b0b65679eb593f32a) (only works for 10k users) to double check. Below is a summary of the number of questions asked per day which are still alive ('OK'), those which have been Deleted (including spam), and Spam posts separately (from [this Metasmoke graph](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?feedback=true+positive&option=graphs&post_type=question&site=4&utf8=%E2%9C%93#graphs)):

| Date | OK | Deleted | Spam |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-10-22 | 9 | 14 | 4 |
| 2018-10-23 | 5 | 20 | 5 |
| 2018-10-24 | 12 | 12 | 4 |
| 2018-10-25 | 13 | 12 | 5 |
| 2018-10-26 | 11 | 13 | 4 |
| 2018-10-27 | 8 | 28 | 11 |
| 2018-10-28 | 7 | 12 | 2 |
| 2018-10-29 | 11 | 31 | 7 |
| 2018-10-30 | 14 | 51 | 7 |

<sub>(the Deleted column will include questions deleted for other reasons than being blatantly off-topic or spam, but those are rare)</sub>

This is how that looks in a graph ([thanks @Shog9](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7337576#7337576)):

[image]

So it looks like this wave started on the 29th, which (coincidentally or not) is the day when the [2018 monthly product team updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305560/2018-monthly-product-team-updates) post was [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) (with [revision 17](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/305560/revisions)). Do the CMs / developers have any way to check if this is really the case, e.g. by checking the Referer header on calls to the [Ask Question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)? I can't remember other featured posts causing similar waves; the last time was when everybody got an [inbox notification about the Terms of Service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278683/statistics-regarding-users-who-recently-flooded-mse-with-blatantly-off-topic-deb/278722#278722), which was a much more prominent 'invite' to Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: I was about to post something about this, but you beat me by a matter of seconds...anyway, I've noticed too that I've been burning through half my daily close votes to VTC these questions.

Comment: Fortunately, nobody is [mass-flagging old questions which should belong on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317009/295232) right now...

Comment: Heh, thanks for the edit. To my defense, I copy/pasted that directly from Excel.

Comment: I did a quick calculation and found that **21** privileged users are required to completely clear the backlog created by a *single* user who uses their full allowance of 100 daily flags to flag old, off-topic questions. When a user earns 3k+ rep, they're then limited to adding only 24 tasks per day to the queue, which only requires 4 other users to clear out. Based on this, do you think it's a good idea to limit RC flags from <3k users to the daily close vote allowance for 3k+ users, regardless of their overall flag allowance?

Comment: I'd prefer the Stack Overflow solution, where the # of close votes is increased to 50 (and CV reviews to 40). Unlike SO, that should be sufficient here. (Rephrased: I want more power myself, I don't care about limiting other user's powers :P)

Comment: Yeah, the close vote limit was increased to 50 during the past ToS notification deluge. It's my fault for letting them know a year and a half later that they forgot to change it back :P

Comment: Related: [Does the new unified design theme result in more off-topic questions where lost users asked on the wrong site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315780/does-the-new-unified-design-theme-result-in-more-off-topic-questions-where-lost) and [People get lost and crash into meta - maybe we need roadblocks for their safety](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306329/people-get-lost-and-crash-into-meta-maybe-we-need-roadblocks-for-their-safety)

Comment: Also related: [Why do users often ask blatantly off-topic questions here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305749/why-do-users-often-ask-blatantly-off-topic-questions-here-on-meta) and [We should ask new users to specify how they got over to ask off-topic question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211675/we-should-ask-new-users-to-specify-how-they-got-over-to-ask-off-topic-question-o)

Comment: Also related: [How can we reduce off-topic questions on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177485/how-can-we-reduce-off-topic-questions-on-meta) and more recently [Downvoting off-topic MSE posts is counterproductive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317379/downvoting-off-topic-mse-posts-is-counterproductive)

Comment: Basically from the quick search I've done, this problem has existed, and continues exist since 2013. Maybe it's time drastic action was taken.

Comment: Three in the space of an hour. :\  At this rate, I'm going to run out of close votes.

Comment: Also I'm earning more helpful flags in the recent time. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A recent email with our quarterly update just went out to *a lot* of people, and it contained a couple of links to MSE.

Last time this happened we just raised the minimum rep to ask, which wasn't ideal. This time we're doing something a bit more permanent, which looks like it'll be an interstitial page that says THIS IS NOT STACK OVERFLOW DO NOT ASK YOUR PROGRAMMING QUESTION HERE (well, it'll be a little more elaborate than that).

I will update. Sorry about that. This wasn't anything like the time we used inbox notifications, and we didn't realize it would cause folks to not realize where they were.

Comment: This could be related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315780/does-the-new-unified-design-theme-result-in-more-off-topic-questions-where-lost?s=1|28.0764

Comment: Do engineers, developers etc. subscribe to SE newsletter w/o first being members of SO? I ask because nearly every single off-topic question was posted by someone with only one rep while v.few newcomers were also members of SO. And it's strange that they post questions, some quite detailed, some simply awful but then they hardly ever reply to comments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not replying to comments is already an existing problem, even if the correct site is chosen.

Comment: So... Thing we gotta remember when talking about this stuff, @Mari-LouA, is that the numbers on SO are insanely high. Apparently we sent out north of two million of these emails... To date, only about 1200 recipients have followed the links to meta, and well under 100 of them have posted off-topic questions. That means two things: *most* people don't get it wrong, and there are potentially still a huge number of people who could still get it wrong.

Comment: So, I'm getting an answer to my question *and* an idea to stop it in the future, all in a single Post? You're spoiling me :P

Comment: Any idea what the interstitial page looks like?  I tried testing it, and I'm not getting one, at least not after clicking Ask Question.

Comment: @fbueckert https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice

Comment: Can we get some stats on how this interstitial page is working?  I'm still seeing a lot of new users confused about what M.SE is for, so knowing it's at least stemming *some* questions would show it's working, albeit not perfectly.

Comment: For those who should have posted on Stack Overflow, it would be interesting to know the percentage who were question-banned at the time of posting on MSE. Even knowing the order, e.g., 1%, 10%, 50% or 90%.

Comment: That is, are they posting here because they are question-banned or because they are confused by the user interface (or something else)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum There's no way to really capture that because some of the blocks are calculated just-in-time, and thresholds have been tweaked over time so you'd have to run each instance through a few models to see if they were likely blocked. However, I can say that with very little variance, _most_ people simply didn't realize that they were on the incorrect site.