# What's with the uptick in blatantly off-topic posts lately?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, off-topic

Generally, we tend to get around a few blatantly off-topic questions here on this site because...[reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305749/why-do-users-often-ask-blatantly-off-topic-questions-here-on-meta).

However, yesterday and today (UTC), I noticed that the number of off-topic questions had increased from normal levels; yesterday, I spent more than half of my daily close vote allowance voting to close these posts, and today, they still continue to pop up.

Is it the [same cause as last Halloween](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317551/what-is-the-cause-of-the-recent-increase-in-blatantly-off-topic-posts-on-meta), in which an email newsletter with links to MSE was sent out? The normal causes I linked above don't seem to apply here, since those normal causes usually produce fewer off-topic questions than lately.

It was also mentioned in that post that the [interstitial page](/questions/ask/advice) was going to be enabled here on this site as a result of the last uptick; was it enabled?

Comment: Possibly related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/ being featured? (just a guess, I don't have data)

Comment: @awizardarachnid That's been featured for days now. I don't think it's the cause, since prior to yesterday it's still been the same usual amount, despite that being featured.

Comment: Spring Break in many parts of North America?

Comment: Posting off-topic questions on Meta is a heck of a way to celebrate Spring Break, @Ward. You must be the life of a party.

Comment: "What are we going to do tomorrow night?" "The same thing we do every night, Pinky - post off-topic questions on Meta Stack Exchange!"

Comment: I was thinking that maybe the number of "real" MSE questions was down because of Spring Break.

Comment: If you aren't subscribed to the RSS feed you have no *idea* how many OT questions pass through here. The majority of questions asked are off topic. The day you asked this question, for example, there were 31 questions asked (assuming none got deleted so fast as to not make the RSS feed). 18 of them were off topic. Weekends are usually worse percentage-wise.